# Loading Google jsapi asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

There was an issue with Google charts today so we're trying to fail gracefully if we can't load the js file. The following works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22visualization%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22corechart%22%5D%7D%5D%7D"></script>
```

The problem is that it will block running other code as it is waiting for the script to time out.

The code below loads,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22visualization%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22corechart%22%5D%7D%5D%7D',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true, // otherwise will get fresh copy every page load
    success: function() {
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 
    }
});
</script>
```

but it errors when I try to use a visualization such as

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Is what I'm doing possible or are we stuck with the problem of if Google is having issues, we just have to wait for the js file to timeout and move on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since you're calling the `google.load` function on success, the `?autoload=...` stuff is redundant.

Just change your url to `//www.google.com/jsapi`, and add a `'callback'` to the `load` call to make sure that your `drawChart` code is called when `corechart` completes.

Here's a JSFiddle and a code snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/c56pC/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: '//www.google.com/jsapi',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    success: function() {
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            'packages': ['corechart'],
            'callback': drawChart
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, new to posting on stack overflow. I thought it would email me. Then I forgot about the question.

Unfortunately, the drawChart code happens only on some pages and at a later time, so I don't think this would work unless we try to load the script just before we needed it, which would slow down those pages.

Answer (score 2):

Your script won't execute once it's downloaded via AJAX. You want to use [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
var url = 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22visualization%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22corechart%22%5D%7D%5D%7D';
$.getScript(url, function() {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry, new to posting on stack overflow. I thought it would email me. Then I forgot about the question.

Unfortunately, the drawChart code happens only on some pages and at a later time, so I don't think this would work unless we try to load the script just before we needed it, which would slow down those pages.